# Unable to convert true/false to 1/0 using xsl:when

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to use XSL to convert XML attributes from having values of "true"/"false" to values of "1"/"0", but I am unable to make the conversion. From reading online, I should be able to use either `<xsl:when>` or `<xsl:if>` to accomplish this. Some references wrap my attribute in `string`, some do not.

Take the example XML:

```
<root>
  <record name="a" isMutable="true">
  <record name="b" isMutable="false">
</root>
```

And the example XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <top>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/record"/>
    </top>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/root/record">
    <xsl:element name="element">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string(@isMutable) = 'true'">
          <xsl:attribute name="when_value">1</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="string(@isMutable) = 'false'">
          <xsl:attribute name="when_value">0</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:attribute name="plain_value"><xsl:value-of select="@isMutable"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="bool_value"><xsl:value-of select="boolean(@isMutable = 'true')"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My hope is to get attributes with `when_value="0"` and `when_value="1"`, instead I get:

```
<top>
  <element plain_value="true" bool_value=""/>
  <element plain_value="false" bool_value=""/>
</top>
```

I can see in the `plain_value` attribute that my attribute value is getting picked up. I also tried an alternate solution which tries to use `boolean`, but you can see that this produces a blank result. Can anyone please point out my syntax error(s) in my example XSL code? Thank you.

Comment: After adding the xsl namespace and version, I couldn't reproduce the problem.. getting the expected output you want..

Comment: Ditto. Since the namespace and version are missing from the posted code, I suspect that you edited the code before posting, and managed to omit whatever it was that was causing he problem.

Comment: It turns out that my ultimate problem was because of Perl. I am using XML::XSLT in Perl to actually convert my XML using this XSL code. And I see now that this Perl XML::XSLT library does not fully support all of the syntax I am using. In trying to simplify my problem for posting, I left out this important detail. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't understand the exact output you want to get. See if the following stylesheet helps:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <top>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="record"/>
    </top>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <element name="{@name}" boolean_value="{@isMutable}" numeric_value="{number(@isMutable='true')}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to a well-formed(!) **test input**:

```
<root>
  <record name="a" isMutable="true"/>
  <record name="b" isMutable="false"/>
</root>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
   <element name="a" boolean_value="true" numeric_value="1"/>
   <element name="b" boolean_value="false" numeric_value="0"/>
</top>
```

As you can see, the value of the `boolean_value` attribute is copied from the original `isMutable` attribute, while the `numeric_value` attribute shows the same value converted to a number - either 1 or 0.

---

For completeness sake, here is how you would do the same thing if you wanted to use `xsl:choose`:

```
<xsl:template match="record">
    <element name="{@name}" boolean_value="{@isMutable}">
        <xsl:attribute name="numeric_value">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@isMutable='true'">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT is a lot more complicated than it needs to be (although, from the looks of it, it *should* work, aside from the missing namespace).

This is all you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@isMutable">
    <xsl:attribute name="when_value">
      <xsl:value-of select="number(. = 'true')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or if you want to handle the case where `@isMutable` could be something other than `true` or `false`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@isMutable[. = 'true' or . = 'false']">
    <xsl:attribute name="when_value">
      <xsl:value-of select="number(. = 'true')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@isMutable">
     <xsl:attribute name="plain_value">
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="bool_value">
       <xsl:value-of select=". = 'true'" />
     </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I will consider using it for future translation.